# How to remove index.php from url in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: laravel-5.1

i am trying to run my project on client's server with the following url:

http://quotes.simplybridal.com/simply-bridal-backend/login     /**/ It Gives 404 Not Found Error**

But it works for:
http://quotes.simplybridal.com/simply-bridal-backend/public/index.php/login   **// It works**

now, my question is how can we remove this index.php from  the url.

here is my .htaccess file content, which i placed outside /public folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /simply-bridal-backend/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: do you have access to your vhosts file?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an Apache issue.

Can you post your Virtual Host content (or .htaccess)?

Check your document root variable (that should be something like /foo/bar/public (with no trailing slash)

--
Put this default .htaccess and make sure the route exists and it is reachable.

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: added .htaccess content, please re-check

Comment: On the contrary, it should be placed inside the public folder. And for sure remove the rule that heads the request into the public folder, there is no need to do that. I do think it should properly work with the default .htaccess

Comment: What does it mean? Still 404? Can you post the route?